# Test for linestring self-intersection with SQL Server

Tags: sql

Is there a query to see whether a linestring is intersecting on itself in SQL Management Studio? The line will be a geometry data type.

The line string can be for example:

```
LINESTRING(318400 745924,318525 745908,318524 745920,318453 745912,318389 745885)
```

Comment: What happens when you run st_isvalid? https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/spatial-geometry/stisvalid-geometry-data-type?view=sql-server-ver15 ?

Answer (score 2):

`STIsSimple` should answer this question:

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/spatial-geometry/stissimple-geometry-data-type?view=sql-server-ver15

> To be simple, a geometry instance must meet all of the following
> requirements:
>
> - Each figure of the instance must not intersect itself, except at its endpoints.
> - No two figures of the instance can intersect each other at a point that is not in both of their boundaries.